# Commit a whole folder with modified files in it with SharpSvn.

Tags: sharpsvn

I am using SharpSvn in my C# project. I am having a folder with some text files in it and another folders with subfolders in it. I am adding the folder under version control and commit it. So far, so good. This is my code:

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
                    {

                        SvnCommitArgs ca = new SvnCommitArgs();

                        SvnStatusArgs sa = new SvnStatusArgs();
                        sa.Depth = SvnDepth.Empty; 

                        Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;

                        client.GetStatus(pathsConfigurator.FranchisePath, sa, out statuses);
                        if (statuses.Count == 1)
                        {
                            if (!statuses[0].Versioned)
                            {
                                client.Add(pathsConfigurator.FranchisePath);
                                ca.LogMessage = "Added";
                                client.Commit(pathsConfigurator.FranchisePath, ca);
                            }
                            else if (statuses[0].Modified)
                            {
                                ca.LogMessage = "Modified";
                                client.Commit(pathsConfigurator.FranchisePath, ca);
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

I make some changes to one of the text files and then run the code againg. The modification is not committed. This condition is false:

```
if (statuses.Count == 1)
```

and all the logic in the if block does not execute.

I have not written this logic and cannot quite get this lines of code:

```
client.GetStatus(pathsConfigurator.FranchisePath, sa, out statuses);
                        if (statuses.Count == 1) {}
```

I went on the oficial site of the API but couldn`t find documentation about this.

1. Can someone that is more familiar with this API tell what these two lines do ?
2. What changes need to be done to this code so if some of the contents of the `pathsConfigurator.FranchisePath` folder are changed, the whole folder with the changes to be commited. Any suggestions with working example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Committing one directory with everything inside is pretty easy: Just call commit on that directory.

The default Depth of commit is `SvnDepth.Infinity` so that would work directly. You can set additional options by providing a `SvnCommitArgs` object to `SvnClient.Commit()`